# Unity Sprites images not updating

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm working on re-skinning a unity game. The game come with unitypackage and I've imported and run it successfully but when I updated images at sprites folder and re-run it won't update the images and strange things some images updated and most of the images are not. Here is the screenshot

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

One big image holds the resources and I need to update that.